# Mapping Json in JDBI RowMapper

Tags: java, database, jdbi, amazon-aurora

I'm using JDBI v 3.11.1 with Amazon Aurora (and Jackson). In our tables, we use JSonB a lot and I feel like the mapping I'm doing is a bit too complicated/slow.

Currently I'm having a DAO doing something like this:

```
@RegisterRowMapper(ContactMapper.class)
  public interface ContactsDao {

    @SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM contacts")
    List<Contact> listContacts();
}
```

while the mapper does something like this: (stripped down to what is needed for this question)

```
public class ContactMapper implements RowMapper<Contact> {

  private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Override
  public Contact map(ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {

    Address address = r.getString("address") == null ? null : (Address) mapJson(r.getString("address"), Address.class);

    return new Contact(
        r.getString("id"),
        address
    );
  }

  private Object mapJson(String json, Class clazz) {
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(json)) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      return objectMapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOGGER.error("Could not map Address.", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

`Address` is stored within Aurora as a JsonB field. I've read something about a `JsonMapper` Annotation but since the jdbi documentation is quite unclear, I'm not sure if this is the right thing.

Is the way how I map my results the "standard" way of doing this or is there a better/more efficient way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: nope. But it proved to be working very stable. Tons of this in prod and not an issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

there is a json plugin, backed by jackson or guava. see http://jdbi.org/#jdbi3-json

if installed, on nested properties like in your case, everything should be mapped correctly as long as the database declares the datatype as "json"/"jsonb" (not string or anything).

furthermore the annotation `@Json` on your sql objects query method should suffice, if not nested (e.g. Contact is a json as a whole)

Answer (score 0):

I'll add to what @winson has recommended. `jdbi3-json` is a great plugin for this but it doesn't provide anything for `RowMapper`s as far as I could see.

I found this workaround which isn't really that cleaner but it would mean the same `ObjectMapper` would be in use if you use the other features of `jdbi3-json`.

```
public Contact map(ResultSet r, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
    var addressMapper = (ColumnMapper<Address>) new JsonColumnMapperFactory()
        .build(Address.class, ctx.getConfig()).orElseThrow();
    return new Contact(
        r.getString("id"),
        addressMapper.map("address")
    );
}
```